# Can someone help translate this seal script (I think)?

Tags: translation, seal

I was told the symbols on this table was seal script. I'm having trouble confirming/translating them. Any help/advice?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 朙（明）⿰古久（故）朙威將
>
> 軍錦衣䘙（衛）⿰扌⿱刀甘（指）
>
> 揮僉事（鄭）公
>
> 曁配（恭）人先
>
> 鐂（鎦）氏繼楊氏
>
> 合（葬）⿵土（墓）誌銘

*Epitaph of joint grave of Grand [Ming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_dynasty) general of the [Embroidered Uniform Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embroidered_Uniform_Guard), Sir* 鄭 *, together with honoured first lady Madame* 鎦 [passed away first] *and second lady Madame* 楊.

(The word choice in this translation might be inappropriate, it's very difficult to translate ancient titles across from Chinese)

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much!