# I need help with an error message [characters recognized: 未检测到U盘1]

Tags: character-identification

A device is showing an error message to me. It is probably about a flash drive or a USB-stick. I'm trying to copy data from the device to a memory card. At first I had errors with drive formatting (which I could solve by automatic translation) but this message stays on the screen for a really short time and I can't get a good picture of it for the recognition algorithms. Can anybody help?

[image: Error message]

Comment: Hi Raul, just FYI in case you encounter the same issue again, [this free OCR tool](https://www.newocr.com/) can identify those characters with 90% accuracy. It only mistakes the third one 测 for 现. I was expecting worse, but in fact it did a decent job even with your blurred image.

Answer (score 2):

The characters in your picture are:

> 未检测到U盘1
>
> USB-stick 1 is not detected.

Comment: While it is normally acceptable to write answers in traditional characters to a question in simplified, in this case the OP is asking to recognize the specific characters shown in the picture, so it makes more sense to reply in simplified.

Comment: @blackgreen We don't have a consistent policy for this (and it might be a good meta question). Personally, I would only enforce a standardisation requirement when we modify the title to include the identified characters, for searchability purposes only. The ability to accurately transcribe something from an image is actually quite difficult \(see [this](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36449/can-someone-help-translate-this-seal-script-i-think)\).